# Proving product of two functions is uniformly continous

Tags: uniform-continuity

If $f$ is bounded and continuous on $(0,1)$ and $g$ is defined on $(0,1)$ as $$g(x)=x(1-x)f(x)$$ how can we show $g$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$?

Comment: Hint: If $f$ is bounded and continuous it's uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$. Try to prove, that given $f,h$ be uniformly continuous and bounded, then $g=fh$ is uniformly continuous. Then show that $h(x) = x(1-x)$ is uniformly continuous and bounded on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Use boundedness of $f$ to observe that $g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ or $x \to 1$. Hence $g$ can be extended to a  continuous function on the compact interval $[0,1]$. This makes $g$ uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$, hence also on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way is that, when function $\phi$ is uniformly continuous on not closed set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then it can be extended on $\overline{A} \setminus A$ by the unique way and obtained function will be  continuous on $\overline{A}$. Now we can use this directly to $g(x)=x(1-x)f(x)$ on $(0,1)$ and obtain $g$ continuous on $[0,1]$, hence,  uniformly continuous.